# How to remove slash from string in C#

Tags: c#, string, slash

I have a string like this:
"/AuditReport"
It is assigned to variable rep.
If I type

```
var r = rep.SysName.Remove(1, 1);
```

It returns "/uditReport" instead of desired "AuditReport",
i.e. it does not remove the slash. How could I remove it?

Comment: Just for reference, `/` is a slash, and \ is a backslash.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

String indices in .NET are zero-based. The documentation for [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx) states that the first argument is *"The zero-based position to begin deleting characters"*.

```
string r = rep.SysName.Remove(0, 1);
```

Alternatively, using [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) is more readable, in my opinion:

```
string r = rep.SysName.Substring(1);
```

Or, you could possibly use [`TrimStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx), depending on your requirements. (However, note that if your string starts with multiple successive slashes then `TrimStart` will remove all of them.)

```
string r = rep.SysName.TrimStart('/');
```

Comment: yea, i see. trying to figure out who was first :)

Comment: Note: most (if not all) indices in .Net are zero-based, not just for strings.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
var r = rep.SysName.Remove(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need:

```
var r = rep.SysName.Remove(0, 1);
```

The first parameter is the start, the second is the number of characters to remove. (1,1) would remove the second character, not the first.

Answer (score 2):

The index is 0-based, so you are removing the second character. Instead, try

```
var r = rep.SysName.Remove(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is about `"/AuditReport".Replace("/","")`?

Comment: That would replace all slashes in the text, OP only wanted to remove the leading slash.

Answer (score 0):

String indexes in .NET is zero based, so:

```
string r = rep.SysName.Remove(0, 1);
```

You can also use:

```
string r = rep.SysName.Substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `var r = rep.SysName.Remove(0, 1);`. I guess you have a VisualBasic background (like me :-) ), arrays, strings, etc in C# start with an index of `0` instead of `1` as in some other languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a `Uri`, you can do it this way:

```
var route = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Path, UriFormat.UriEscaped);
```

It will return for example `api/report` rather than `/api/report`.